# Why doesn't this work? (toLocaleString on some outputs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this basic calculator below, and I'm using toLocaleString to add a separator inside the numbers so it reads easier. It works perfectly on the third output, but not on the first two? I have basic coding skills so I'm not 100% sure how to use it...

```
<form oninput="loanval.value=loan.value.toLocaleString(); periodval.value=period.value.toLocaleString(); paymentval.value=Math.floor(loan.value / period.value).toLocaleString()">

<label>Loan Amount</label>
<input type="range" id="loan" name="loan" min="5000" max="400000" step="5000">              
<output name="loanval" for="loan">0</output>

<label>Loan Period</label>
<input type="range" id="period" name="period" min="1" max="15">          
<output name="periodval" for="period">0</output>

<label>Your monthly repayment will be:
<output name="paymentval">0</output>

</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because per default, your form input is a `string` and `toLocaleString` works on numbers. So, to change it accordingly, you have to change your `loan.value` to `parseInt(loan.value, 10)` as you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5m0fL7La/)

That said, the `Math` js functions implicitly do the conversion above for you, so that's why your last output works as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I understand it better now, and works perfectly :)

Comment: Had the same 'problem' and couldn't find out what it was. Totaly overlooked that .value would be a string. Thanks !